# How to use Recursion to get child tree items in Vaadin?

Tags: java, recursion, vaadin

I am trying to get child items of a Vaadin tree when the parent is clicked. I am attempting to use recursion by creating a separate method to traverse the tree, but I'm stuck. This is what I have so far:

```
public Collection<?> recursiveTreeSearch(Object objectItemID, Collection<?> siblings){

    if (evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().hasChildren(objectItemID)==true){

        siblings = evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(objectItemID);

        for (int i = 0; i < evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(objectItemID).size(); i++) {

            recursiveTreeSearch(objectItemID, siblings); 
        }

    } 

    return siblings;
};
```

This ends up being an infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think without testing, its because you never reduce the amount of siblings of your tree....Therefore your method is called all the time with the same parameters and can never end

Comment: I think evoltWebUI never changes/swaps so you end up recursing over and over the object. If it has children it will always recurse. That is the testing you need to do as mentioned before

Comment: Make evoltWebUI a param. Test if the current child has children then recurse

Comment: @efekctive - Should I make it a third parameter?

Comment: Yes, but why are you passing the parameter siblings? I have not looked at the code thoroughly but it may be extra

Comment: @efekctive - Because I am getting the parent from an item event in a click listener in another method. I'm not sure if this is the best way to get the event from the click listener over to my recursive method.

Comment: Get the infinite loop solved then get efficient. It is what I would do

Comment: What's wrong with an `ItemClickListener` and `tree.getChildren(event.itemId())`? This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711628/get-sibling-of-vaadin-tree-item/38716956#38716956) gets the siblings of the clicked node, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to get all the *decendants* (nodes of the subtree), not only its children. To get the children simply *getChildren()* would be enough. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology for terminology.

The issue is that you are calling the same method recursively with the same parameters. What you meant is probably the following:

```
public Collection<?> recursiveTreeSearch(Object objectItemID, Collection<?> siblings){

        if (evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().hasChildren(objectItemID)==true){
            // here you had an issue as well, as your line in fact did nothing visible to the caller
            siblings.addAll(evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(objectItemID));

            for (int i = 0; i < evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(objectItemID).size(); i++) {
                // here was your bug:
                recursiveTreeSearch(evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(objectItemID).get(i), siblings); 
            }
        } 

        return siblings;
    };
```

This should not produce an infinite loop and return the desired result. Use it like this: *recursiveTreeSearch(itemId, new ArrayList())*.

To make the method look nicer and slightly more efficient you should extract the children object to a local variable, use a foreach loop, name the method and parameters better:

```
    public Collection<?> getDescendants(final Object itemId) {
        return getDescendantsRec(itemId, new ArrayList<Object>());
    }

    private Collection<?> getDescendantsRec(final Object itemId, final Collection<Object> siblings) {

            Collection<?> childrenIds = evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(itemId);

            if (childrenIds.size() > 0){
                siblings.addAll(childrenIds);

                for (Object childItemId : childrenIds) {
                    getDescendantsRec(childItemId, siblings); 
                }
            } 

            return siblings;
        };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps make recursion clearer to me. However I get an error on "siblings.addAll(childrenIds);"  It doesn't want to add the siblings collection to the childrenids collection. I get this error when I hover over: "The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#4-of ?>) in the type Collection<capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<capture#5-of ?>)". Any suggestion?

Comment: Also, itemId in the for loop is underlined as a duplicate variable name. Should this be itemId2 or something differently named?

Comment: I get error on "Collection<Object> childrenIds = evoltWebUI.getPrimaryTreeView().getChildren(itemId);" It says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<capture#2-of ?> to Collection<Object>". Also, when I'm ready to get the children, I'd just call getDescendants with the itemID only? Is that correct?